# Laravel: getting error when trying to return specific orders to a user

Tags: laravel

```
public function user(Request $request, $user_id){

    return Order::where('user_id', '=', `$user_id`);

}
```

Gives me the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the
> type string or null, object given, called in
> /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line
> 72

I want to be able to return the orders to the user based on their user id passed in as the route parameter.

Comment: I was missing the ->get() from the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

2 things to do:

1. remove the `` around `$user_id` variable
2. Add ->get() at the end of your statement to get the collection of results.

```
public function user(Request $request, $user_id){

    return Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get();

}
```

If you are doing a ajax request you will have to return a response:

```
public function user(Request $request, $user_id){

    return response()->json(['orders' => Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get()])

}
```